# How to split a string by comma ignoring comma in double quotes

Tags: regex, powershell, split

This question has been asked before but I have been trying to work a solution in **powershell** but am not getting the desired results.

```
$line = '1,2,"N",09/04/13,"P09042013ZSD(1,0)","ZSD"'
[string[]] $splitColumns = $line.Split('(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)', [StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries')
```

When I loop though the split values I am expecting

```
1
2
"N"
09/04/13
"P09042013ZSD(1,0)"
"ZSD"
```

But am getting

```
1
2
N
09/04/13
P09042013ZSD
1
0
ZSD
```

I have tested the regex using http://regexhero.net/tester/ (Split) with ExplicitCapture set and it returns the desired results.

**Working solution**

```
$RegexOptions = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]
$csvSplit = '(,)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)'

$splitColumns = [regex]::Split("StringHere", $csvSplit, $RegexOptions::ExplicitCapture)
```

Comment: You can simply Use Just Implode & expload for that...

Comment: I guess those are cells from a csv file or so? I'd rather make sure to have an unused character like `;` for the separator in the source file.

Comment: Source file cannot be touched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[string].split()` method doesn't accept `regex` on split but just `[char[]]` or `[string[]]`.

You can try like this:

```
 $line -split ',(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)'
```

powershell `-split` accept `regex` for splitting text

Using .net you can do it like this:

```
[regex]::Split( $line , ',(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)' )
```

Comment: I also tried -split. It added the , as extra lines i.e. 1 , 2 would be 3 items. Is there anyway to remove these , entries such as how StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries' worked?

Comment: @DavidLiddle Have you tried my code? I've removed the capture on `,`

Comment: I got it working with the [regex]::Split and RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture.

Comment: If you remove the capture group on `,` you can avoid the `regexoptions`